# When Opening Files in C why do I have to use a different Macro to define the file then I use to declare the File Pointer?

Tags: c, file

I have been playing with text files in C and have found out macros get weird when interacting with text files.

So can someone explain to me why this compiles...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define FILENAME "Distribution.txt"

int main()
{
    float zvalue[13][10];

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("Distribution.txt", "r");

    for (int a=0; a<13; a++) {
    for (int b=0; b<10; b++) {
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &zvalue[a][b]);
    }
    }

    printf("%f", zvalue[0][0]);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
    //This compiles
}
```

But when line three is changed to FILE instead of FILENAME it does not?

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define FILE "Distribution.txt"

int main()
{
    float zvalue[13][10];

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("Distribution.txt", "r");

    for (int a=0; a<13; a++) {
    for (int b=0; b<10; b++) {
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &zvalue[a][b]);
    }
    }

    printf("%f", zvalue[0][0]);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
    //This does not compile

}
```
````

Comment: In your second code snippet, all occurrences of `FILE` after the `#define...` line are replaced with `"Distribution.txt"`. So, the `FILE* fp;` becomes `"Distribution.txt"* fp;` - which (clearly) cannot compile.

Answer (score 0):

`FILE` is defined by the C standard.  It is the type that the `fopen` returns a pointer to.  If you look a few lines down in your code, you can see that you are using `FILE` for that purpose.  Therefore, redefining it can cause all sorts of problems and you should not do it.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. Have a great rest of your day.

Answer (score 0):

Macros are automatic copy/paste.

When you write

```
#define FILE "Distribution.txt"
```

it tells the compiler that from now on, whenever you wrote `FILE`, it should pretend you wrote `"Distribution.txt"` instead.

So then when it sees this line:

```
FILE *fp;
```

it pretends you wrote this line:

```
"Distribution.txt" *fp;
```

which is not valid.